# Wondering what the phrases " vast arcs" and " could do no better" mean . From reuters

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

That has led them to focus on hijacking or sabotage, but they have not ruled out technical problems. Faint electronic "pings" detected by a commercial satellite suggested it flew for another six hours or so, but could do no better than place its final signal on one of two vast arcs.

http://mobile.reuters.com/article/topNews/idUSBREA2701720140323?irpc=932

Answer (score 2):

"Arc", here, may have its mathematical meaning: part of the perimeter a circle (or, more generally, a curved line). E.g. the ping was detected by one satellite, but without more information (e.g. more pings, more satellites), it's not possible to know exactly where the plane was, only that it was somewhere along a line.

Using "arc" more figuratively, it could mean any sort of line or region.

"Two vast arcs" would simply mean that there are two *very big* [vast] lines or regions where the final signal could have been sent from. Maybe there are two because there are places where it is known not to be - or maybe it's to do with the uncertainty of the data. It is not clear from the article, as far as I can tell. (Damkerng T.: See the illus. below)

"[They] could do not better than X" = "X was the best that they could do".

So to put it all together: "[Investigators] could do not better than place its final signal on one of two vast arcs" = "All that the investigators know is that the final signal was on one of two lines".

[image]

Comment: I just found this diagram, so I added it to your answer. I hope you wouldn't mind it.